# sklearn OneHotEncoder outputs non-array object error

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working through a Python Machine Learning Course on Udemy on the following dataset (showing the first few rows only)

```
   R&D Spend  Administration  Marketing Spend       State  Profit
0     165349          136898           471784    New York  192262
1     162598          151378           443899  California  191792
2     153442          101146           407935     Florida  191050
3     144372          118672           383200    New York  182902
```

The course was made in 2016 so some of the modules have been updated and I have changed this in my code (e.g: using ColumnTransformer make_column_transformer). The output of this code **should be** a float array (and it is in the Udemy tutorial) however, for some reason, after the code updates, my variable `x` is considered to be an `ndarray object` after carrying out the processing on it. I am not sure why because when I print the variable `x` it prints out an array of floats.

The original data file can be found at [this link](https://sds-platform-private.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/P14-Multiple-Linear-Regression.zip) (a zip folder) in the file `50_startups.csv`.

I tried adding `.toarray()` but this broke the code.

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

dataset = pd.read_csv("Startups (multiple linear regression).csv")
x=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,-1]


#Encode categorical variables (New York, California, Florida)
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer, make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
preprocess = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(),[-1]),remainder="passthrough")
x = preprocess.fit_transform(x)
```

[image]

Comment: where exactly and what is the error?

Comment: So the code runs perfectly. The error is with the output variable ```x```. It should output an array that can be viewed using spyders array editor/viewer however the output ```x``` is an ndarray object and spyder cannot open it using its array editor. Do you have any idea why? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I think this is just a result of the mixed data types in your input and outputs. For example if you examine `x`:

```
x
array([[165349, 136898, 471784, 'New York'],
       [162598, 151378, 443899, 'California'],
       [153442, 101146, 407935, 'Florida'],
       [144372, 118672, 383200, 'New York']], dtype=object)
```

You will see that it has `dtype=object`. This is because of the mix of integers and strings in the array. Because of that the passthrough array (R&D Spend, Administration, and Marketing Spend) maintain the same `dtype`. Within `fit_transform` this array is then stacked with the result of your `OneHotEncoder` transformation to produce the result. In this way the output `dtype` is the same as the input you provided.

If you want to change the `dtype` you can always just use `.astype(float)`.